# tomcat throwing java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null when application running behind elb and response is streamed on http

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jersey, streaming, amazon-elb

I am stuck in one of the problem from last few days :
    I have a spring boot application running on aws ecs which is behind elb.
    The application is exposing a jersey end point which is downloading a 750 MB
    file from aws-s3 in chunks. We are taking input stream from s3 and 
    streaming it on HTTP. In mid of it's download (at around 400 MB download), we get below **exception**.

```
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: 
     java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:380)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96  )
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:134)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1221)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:378)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:347) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:561)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
```

I research this and found some common solutions on google indicating to keep : idle time out of `elb` to higher value, and set `keepalivetimeout` of      tomcat to higher value, when i set both these properties to 1800, it started to work, but I don't want to set these value to some no: without       understanding the root cause.

Also, I went into tomcat classes and found the actual line of code which is throwing the exception, but still not able to figure out the cause.

Also, not able to understand why this is happening only when application is 
behind aws-elb. 
Do anyone have clue on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the similar issue with you, let me try to explain the root cause of the problem: 
The data stream flow is from "Spring Boot Application"-->ELB-->Client.The "Spring Boot Application" and ELB are located on the same network, so the network speed between them is very fast.  But the network speed between ELB and Client is not so fast.
Let us assume the case if the ELB memory buffer and network buffer are filled with data because the data is not transported to Client in time,  what will happened:  the SocketTimeoutException will be thrown because the tiny 4k bytes cannot be sent to the ELB within “timeout” seconds due to there is not enough space to accept the data from "Spring Boot Application"(which is supposed to be finished instantly).
So my guess is that the issue can always happen if the timeout is small enough or the network speed between ELB and Client is slow enough.

Comment: You can mimic a slow client by calling sleep, then try to reproduce the bug against the new keepalivetimeout parameter. My guess is that the bug happens again.